# rails serving different content types through a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a cms system for multiple clients. 
Now i have the following controller:
websites with 2 methods: 
index and public.

I would like to serve different types of content through that method. 
So it could be images, js, css etc.

But how to accomplish this! 
of course i have this extention.. for example /index.css
i check if it exists and then i want to render it. 
But how to do this with different types of content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `respond_to`?

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # will render views/some_controller/index.html.erb
    format.js # will render views/some_controller/index.js.erb
  end
end
```

etc

Comment: thanxs!. but it is actually in websites/#{client_id}/ So that would only work if it would be in the views dir. Also i doubt that it would render images :P

Comment: OH edit.. my bad. i read up .. maybe it is possible! thanxs! :) (i will give it a try..

Comment: well i edited the mime_types.. so my app now supports everything! ;)